# Why is 'pip show json' showing warning

Tags: python, json

I wrote `pip show json`, but it shows a warning saying

> "WARNING: Package(s) not found: json".

I have already run the program many times with json functions, so I know that it is installed, so why can't I check which version it is? What can I do to check the json version?

Comment: on windows: `pip freeze | findstr json` or on linux: `pip freeze | grep json`

Comment: As explained in the documentation https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_show/, the command pip show "Show information about one or more installed packages.".
json, datetime, unittest, etc ... are considered as built-in package so they are defacto not shown into your requirements.txt - this is why you have this package not found warning.

Comment: `json` is a part of the standard library (_"batteries included"_), so its version == Python's version.

Comment: @Bloodbee so the json version is just the version of my python?

Answer (score 1):

The `json` module is built into Python itself; it isn't separately downloaded, so it has no separate version.

You can verify that multiple ways:

- It's listed at https://docs.python.org/3/library/
- `import json; print(json.__file__)` shows a location that's *not* under `site-packages` (where downloaded content goes).